# Admob Test Ads are showing but not shown real ads

Tags: android-studio

Admob Test Ads are showing but not shown real ads

I write adRequest.addTestDevice("DEVICE_ID") showing test ads

When i remove this line ads are not shown
In logcat shown - i/ads failed to load 3.

[image: screenshot test ad]

Comment: Hello Aagman. Could you please provide some more deetails. Maybe some code and the error messages?

Comment: error log -   W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings ,  W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false